# Animation Fragment with text from Database

Tags: java, android

I'm new at this and I need your help! I want to make an animation of the transition from one text to another using fragments.

I load the text from the database. Can you help me realise this?

Loading text from the database.

```
public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private Context context;
private TextView text;

public GetData(Context context, TextView text) {
    this.text=text;
    this.context=context;
}

protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String result = "";
    try {
        String link = "https://solidifiable-airfie.000webhostapp.com/change.php";
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("id", "UTF-8") + "=" + "id";
        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
        }
        reader.close();
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    this.text.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private boolean mShowingBack = false;
private TextView txt,txt1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    assert frameLayout != null;
    frameLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flipText();
        }
    });
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new LyricsENG())
                .commit();
    }
}

private void flipText() {
    if (mShowingBack) {
        mShowingBack = false;
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        mShowingBack = true;
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(
                        R.animator.text_flip_right_enter,
                        R.animator.text_flip_right_exit,
                        R.animator.text_flip_left_enter,
                        R.animator.text_flip_left_exit)
                .replace(R.id.container, new
                        LyricsRU())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Fragment 1

```
public class LyricsENG extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lyrics_eng, container, false);
    }
}
```

Fragment 2

```
public class LyricsRU extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lyrics_ru, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do have any common view in both fragment ?

Comment: Please paste code instead of screenshot.

Comment: Consider not to use `AsyncTask`, it will be deprecated in Android 11, instead rxjava or kotlin coroutines can be used.